# New Gaming PC not responsive as fast as supposed to

Tags: hard-drive, performance, computer-building

I build my Gaming PC for around 1000$. Quad core, 8 gb ram.
And its not very fast/ responsive. My 6 years old dell is more responsive than it. For instance: openning the software Google Chrome takes around 5 seconds. Which is weird for a new pc.
I have no idea what could be the problem and this is bugging me alot. Help please

```
CPU i5 Quad core
MB : MSI z87-G43
GPU GeForce 770
RAM: 8GB DDR3
I have an old HDD: 1.5 Tb WD15EARs-00S8B1
OS: windows 8
```

Comment: really looks like the HDD could the bottleneck here - the rest of the hardware is sound. What OS?

Comment: If your going to get decent hardware like that get an SSD for your OS driver and it will be a lot faster.

Comment: HDD is a bottleneck, always. Get an SSD and install OS and the software which you want to open fast. I can say an SSD increases performance by at least 2-3 times (response time).

Comment: OS is Windows 8

Comment: I had an SDD before, but it always made my computer crash, and 64 GB is too small

Comment: Are we certain it was the SSD causing the `6 years old dell` to crash?

Comment: @Oxymoron Sorry, I meant to say that I used an SDD on my new PC before, but went back to my old HDD

Comment: Are we certain it was the SSD causing the gaming PC to crash? What errors did you get?

Comment: @Oxymoron Computer simply crashed and didnt want to boot. Seemed like the SDD caused corrupted files all over the PC

Comment: Millions of apple users have a ssd and don't experience crashes the ssd is unlikely the cause.

Comment: does dxdiag show any issues? do you have an active antivirus system installed? they can really impact the launch time of apps. also what kind of games are you running? are all your drivers installed and current (especially your chipset drivers)? as for your SSD, if you switch from PATA to AHCI drivers, windows will not boot correctly, so that may be the cause of your issue. you can try setting the ssd to PATA in your bios, and then once booted, look into installing the windows drivers for AHCI.

Answer (score 2):

Check you're task manager and resource monitor and make sure that no bloatware is hogging your resources. Then verify your event logs to ensure nothing is hanging due to errors. Finally check your device manager and ensure and devices are reported to be functioning normally. If all the above come out A-OK, upgrade that hard drive.

**Pro Tip**: Really wanna see a boost in performance, Invest into a [solid state drive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKcSxd_ynsM)

Comment: Thanks, but where is the
Resource monitor and the event log?

Comment: @Conrad You are using windows 8 right? Just type in "Resource Monitor" or "Event Log" in the home menu and they should show up.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain 44 warnings and 1 error in the last 24h in the event log. Is this OK?

Comment: Depends on what the warning and errors say. If they look relevent edit your original question to include them.

Comment: Ideally, the only errors you should see, are the ones you expect to see.